# JaCaMo cannot satisfy dependencies in Eclipse. Missing requirement

Tags: java, installation, error-handling, dependencies, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to follow the JaCaMo Eclipse Plugin instructions. I am getting a problem when installing a new software. Can anyone help? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDVAs.png)

I tried to follow instructions but cannot solve the issue above. I have looked but cannot see anyone having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The problem is with the version of Eclipse. I'm assuming you're using a version that's 2021-12 or later. After the whole fiasco with Log4j at the end of 2021, I believe they stopped using it or changed something about it in Eclipse, and hence the error. Using Eclipse with versions 2021-09 or before will solve the issue.